# ¿Como convertir un tipo MaybeLocal String a un std string?

Tags: c++, nodejs

estoy haciendo un `addon` para `nodejs` en `c++`, soy mu nuevo en `c++` por cierto, lo que intento hacer es una función en `javascript` que reciba un objeto y este convertirlo a un `std::string` en `c++`, hasta ahora después de investigar en google, he logrado convertir el objeto que se pasa desde `javascript` a un objeto `Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String>` usando el ejemplo que está en la documentación de `Nan`.

Mi función de `c++` está así:

```
void ParseJSONToJSONString(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info){

    v8::Isolate* isolate = info.GetIsolate();

    if(info.Length() != 1){
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(
            v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Se esperaba 1 argumento.")));
        return;
    }

    //Usando el ejemplo

    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = Nan::To<v8::Object>( info[0] ).ToLocalChecked();

    Nan::JSON NanJSON;
    Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String> result = NanJSON.Stringify( obj );

    //Y ahora quisiera convertir la variable "result" que se supone que contiene el objeto que se paso desde javascript ya convertido en string, en un "std::string" 

}
```

Desde `javascript` la función se llama de esta manera:

```
var dbm = require('./dbm');
//El modulo que estoy haciendo se llama 'dbm' por cierto.

dbm.saveJSONString({
    uno: 1,
    dos: "dos"
});
```

Lo que quisiera es convertir esa variable de tipo `Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String>` a un `std::string` para poder tratarla como `std::string`.

Muchas gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoría lo que tienes que hacer es convertir el objeto `MaybeLocal` en un `Local`. Después extraes la secuencia de caracteres UTF y, con esa cadena, ya puedes crear el objeto `std::string`:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> v8_string = /* ... */;
Nan::Utf8Value nan_string(v8_string);
std::string std_string(*nan_string);
```